# Cannot rerun my app with guard or rerun

Tags: ruby, guard

So I have an app, the tree is something like this:

```
- Gemfile
- Guardfile
- source/
- dist/
- app.rb
```

The command to start the server is `ruby app.rb` ( or `require_relative './app.rb'`, which does the same thing)

I want to run this command and re run it whenever any file changes.

The only exception is the dist/ folder - any file changes in there should be ignored.

Here's my attempt so far with `guard` and `guard-shell` (apologies for the code dump):

```
require 'childprocess'

# Global constant tracking whether the app has been started
RunningProcess = {gen_rb: false}

# Method to stop the app if it's been started
def ensure_exited_server
  begin
    RunningProcess[:gen_rb] && RunningProcess[:gen_rb].poll_for_exit(10)
  rescue ChildProcess::TimeoutError
    RunningProcess[:gen_rb].stop # tries increasingly harsher methods to kill the process.
  end
  nil
end

# Start the app using 'child-process'
def start_app
  # prevent 'port in use' errors
  ensure_exited_server
  # The child-process gem starts a process and exposes its stdout
  RunningProcess[:gen_rb] = ChildProcess.build("ruby", "gen.rb")
  RunningProcess[:gen_rb].io.inherit!
  RunningProcess[:gen_rb].start
  nil
end

# Always start the app, not just when a file changes.
start_app

# The guard-shell gem runs a block whenever some set of files has changed.
guard :shell do
  # This regex matches anything except the dist/ folder
  watch /^[^dist\/].+/ do |m|
    start_app
    # Print a little message when a file changes.
    m[0] + " has changed."
  end
  nil
end

# Make sure the app does not run after guard exits
at_exit { ensure_exited_server }
```

This doesn't ever restart my app.

The problem with rerun is something I raised an issue on their repo about: see https://github.com/alexch/rerun/issues/107

Comment: What version of Ruby and what version of Guard?

Comment: guard 2.14.0, ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this for your Guardfile?

```
guard :shell do
  watch(%r{^source/.+\.(rb)}) do |m|
    `ruby app.rb`
  end

  watch('app.rb') do |m|
    `ruby app.rb`
  end
end
```

Instead of listing which directories to ignore, this `watch` states which directories/files to use.

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question, but i have slim, rb, coffee, sass, and js files which the app precompiles and I need to watch.  I was hoping to use `--ignore` so that I could have source files in top level folders other than source/.

Comment: Awesome, I got it working with your suggestion to include rather than exclude in the regex. I'm doing the `exclusion` check with `start_app unless m.instance_variable_get("@original_value").to_s.include?("dist/")`.

Comment: I'm still interested to know if the `exclude` regex pattern is fundamentally broken in guard, or if there's something wrong with my original approach.